# how to put image location in javascript code in a django template

Tags: javascript, django, image, templates

I am using a javascript file to do some button displays .When a user clicks on a button ,the current button's image  is replaced by another image (thus creating the effect that a new button appears in place of the old one) and vice versa.I created an `<img>` element with an id='imgbutton' and uses the elements `attr('src',newimage)` to display these buttons.

I was putting the javascript file in `{{MEDIA_URL}}/js` directory sothat the file can be added to template using

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/js/myscript.js" ></script>
```

In the javascript code(jquery 1.7.1),I am setting the image like this

```
..
var btnimg=$('#imgbutton');
btnimg.attr('src','{{MEDIA_URL}}/img/NewImage.png');
```

This causes a `404 error` in javascript console..and a placeholder is shown instead of the image.
In the django templates ,the `{{MEDIA_URL}}/img/OldImage.png` is properly displayed..it is only in the javascript that the problem occurs..Can someone help me figure out why this happens?How do I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the JS file is not processed by Django's template engine. When I need to do this I normally put a small bit of JS directly in the the page to set variable values, and then that is referenced by the JS file that is loaded with the `<link>` tag.

**Update:**

Yes, you want to do something like this:

```
<script>
// first set the value you will be using.
var MEDIA_URL = "{{MEDIA_URL}}"; // and anything else you need to set
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/js/myscript.js" ></script>
```

Now you can reference that global value *inside* the JS file, e.g.:

```
btnimg.attr('src',MEDIA_URL+'/img/NewImage.png');
```

If there are a lot of these things, an Array or Object that holds all of them keeps your namespace tidy.

Comment: does that mean the media url string should be captured in a variable and passed to the javascript code which sets the image?

Comment: It is not "passed" to the code. It is simply set in the global scope; then the other code bits use it.